# See waiting print jobs for Google Cloud Print

Tags: google-chrome, google-cloud-print

Is there any way that I can see waiting print jobs for Google Cloud Print for Google Chrome? I'm trying to print out 5 documents using Google Cloud Print, but only two of them have printed so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can access your print jobs at https://www.google.com/cloudprint/manage.html#jobs

For more details, you can refer to the [Google Cloud Print documentation](http://support.google.com/cloudprint/?hl=en#2541639).

Comment: also answers the question: "how do I clear google cloud print job list" (using delete button on your first link"